# Multi-derivative of standard normal CDF

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to solve the following $m$th-derivative of standard normal cdf,
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m}\Phi \left(\frac{a+\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right),$$
where $m> 0$ is an integer , $\mu>0$, and $u>0$ are constants. $a>0$.

After trying to do this with Maple, found it hard to reach a closed form of solution.The length of derivative increases as $m$ increases.

This problem comes from
    $$\begin{split}
&\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m}\left(\int_{0}^{u}\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}} e^{-\frac{(a+\mu x)^2}{2x}}dx \right)\\
= & \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m}\left( \mathbb{P}(\tau_{a}<u)\right)\\
= & \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m}\left(\mathbb{P}(\max_{0\leq s\leq u} (W_{t}-\mu t)\geq a)\right)\\
= & \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m} \left( 1- \Phi (\frac{a+\mu u}{\sqrt{u}})+e^{-2\mu a}\bar{\Phi}(\frac{a-\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}) \right)
\end{split},$$
where $\tau _a$ is the first hitting time when the drifted Brownian motion $W_t-\mu t$ touches the barrier $a$.

Any help or idea for this problem would be the most grateful.

---

Edit: The hint provided by Did in the comment is very helpful and does work, since 
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m}\Phi \left(x\right)=(-1)^{m-1}H_{m-1}(x)\phi(x).$$

---

Just got another question about the following multi-derivative
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m} \left(e^{-2\mu a}\Phi \left(\frac{a-\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\right),$$
I tried to find
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} \left(e^{bx}\Phi \left(x\right)\right)$$
firstly, but it seems be very difficult to get a recursive answer like the first multi-derivative.

Any help or idea would be the most grateful.

Comment: Hint: Use that $\Phi'=\varphi$ and $\varphi'(x)=-x\varphi(x)$. The result should be $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m}\Phi \left(\frac{a+\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt{u}}\right)^mH_{m-1} \left(\frac{a+\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\varphi \left(\frac{a+\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right),$$ for some polynomial $H_m$ of degree $m$. These, or some simple transform of these, are often called the Hermite polynomials and solve the recursion $H_0(x)=1$ and $$H_{m+1}(x)=H'_m(x)-xH_m(x).$$

Comment: @Did, Thank you so much for your help. Yes, I have understood it, just found a minor mistake in the answer, there should be $(-1)^{m-1}$, since the recursion in the Hermite polynomial seems to be like this actually, $$H_{m+1}(x)=xH_{m}(x)-{H_m}'(x)$$. Anyway, many thanks for your hint.